# Plot text subscript with comma between two values

Tags: r, plot, expression

I want to write the following text when I plot something in R. Here the subscript is Greek letters alpha and nu with a comma in between.

[image]

I tried the following code but didn't get comma and nu.

```
plot(1, 1, main = expression(t[alpha, nu]))
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `paste()` to include the comma:

```
plot(1, 1, main = expression(t[paste(alpha, ",", nu)]))
```

giving

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We can also use `bquote`

```
plot(1, 1, main = bquote(t[alpha*","*nu]))
```

[image]

Or as @Roland mentioned, `quote` would also work

```
plot(1, 1, main = quote(t[alpha*","*nu]))
```

Comment: This is the what I would use, but there is no need for `bquote`. You can just use `expression` or `quote`.